# Pythonic and SQLAlchemy best way to map data that requires multiple lookups

Tags: python-2.7, select, join, sqlalchemy, union

I'm learning SQLAlchemy and using a database where multiple table lookups are needed to find a single piece of data.

I'm trying to find the best (most efficient and Pythonic) way to map the multiple lookups to a single SQLAlchemy object or reusable python method.

Ultimately, there will be dozens if not hundreds of mapped object such as these, so something like a .map file might be handy.

I.e. (Using pseudocode)

If I want to find the data 'Status' from 'Patient Name' have to use three tables.

[image]

Instead of writing a function for every potential 'this' to 'that' data request, is there an SQLAlchemy or Pythonic way to make the mappings?

I CAN make new, temporary SQLAlchemy Tables to store data. I am NOT at liberty to change the database I'm reading from. I'm hoping to reduce the number of individual calls to the database, because it is remote and slow.

I'm not sure a data join will work, because the Primary Keys, Foreign Keys and Column names are inconsistent in the database. But, I don't really know how to make select-joins in SQLAlchemy.

Perhaps I need to create a new table, with relationships to those three previous tables? But I'm not understanding the relationships well.

Can these tables be auto-generated from a map.ini file?

EDIT:
I might add, that some of these relationships could be one to many. I.e. a patient may be associated with more than one statusID...such as...

[image]

Comment: You should do a join. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Primary Keys, Foreign Keys and Column names are inconsistent in the database", but as long as you know the names of columns (which you need anyway to do it any other way, even if they are inconsistent) and which columns refer to the same thing (i.e. the join condition), you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The issue here is; when try to do a join between (in the example) the 'Patient_status' and Status_ID', I get an error "sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'Patient_status' and 'Status_ID'." As I mentioned I can't modify the database to add the foreign key relationship.

Comment: You don't need a foreign key in the database. You just need to define it in SQLAlchemy. In fact, you don't need a foreign key at all because you can specify the join condition directly: `db.session.query(Patient_status).join(Patient_name, Patient_status.PatientId == Patient_name.PatientId)`.